# White and Hexadecimal boxes instead of regular characters after upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 LST

Tags: upgrade

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 LST to the 20.04 LST. In the upgraded version the name of files/folders/programs all are appearing as the white boxes (see the attached pictures below) and terminal text is appearing as the hexadecimal boxes. The main difficulty is the inability to use a terminal or programs to solve this issue due to the lack of readable fonts.

Has anyone ever had this issue? What are the possible ways to solve this? Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

[image: White boxes instead of text]